# Renew Kerberos Ticket with Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have implemented kerberos in our kafka cluster recently.Clients need to use SASL_SSL for talking to this cluster.As we are using spring-kafka in our projects,I came across this KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer module from spring documentation.I think we can leverage this feature but wanted to understand if this provides any feature to renew the ticket (may be on a different thread)when ticket expires. I looked at the code and see that the options passed  in the map are then used to initiate a javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry instance but did not see a way to do auto renewal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it's simply a Spring-friendly alternative to providing the `-Djava.security.auth.login.config` JVM argument.

Renewing kerberos tickets is outside the scope of Spring for Apache Kafka; all broker connection-related operations are delegated to the kafka-clients; refer to the Kafka documentation.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Any thoughts on how to do this from a spring perspective in general using this bean KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer . Thinking in lines of a @Scheduled or I could also  start a thread when KafkaMessageListenerContainer  bean is created(in case of a consumer) and have it wait until  the next renewal  interval .I also wonder how KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer  will be useful in  real scenarios where  the applications that talk to kafka are typically long running .Does it make sense to have a renewal period configured in a future release?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Kerberos or what's involved with performing the renewal. I assumed it was just configuring some Kafka properties. Certainly if there's something the project can do to help, we can look at it. Contributions are welcome.

Comment: I think renewTGT=true in jaas config should make this work without any other changes https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4837364

Comment: Looks like [KIP-368](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-368%3A+Allow+SASL+Connections+to+Periodically+Re-Authenticate) has added re-auth in the upcoming 2.2 kafka-clients.